# Successfully installed azure toolkit for java plugin for eclipse but not showing any option “New Azure Deployment Project”

Tags: java, azure

I have successfully installed azure toolkit for java plugin for eclipse from  http://dl.msopentech.com/eclipse via "install new software" option  but not showing any option “New Azure Deployment Project” or I am unable to create any Azure Deployment Project. I need this solution please help all.

Comment: Could you tell me the eclipse version which you used? or You could install another version of eclipse and install the toolkit again. you could download eclipse(Eclipse Neon.1 (4.6.1)) from this URL  http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/

Comment: i used both eclipse LUNA and MARS, but not get any result..

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, the following steps may be useful for you.

1.You should use a pure Eclipse Environment and you could get a pure eclipse from this URL http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/.

2.You could click Help->Installation Details in order in your eclipse Env and then you could select Configuration pane.
    After, you could click View Error Log to see whether there are some plug-in conflict error.
[image] 
3.You could get the Plug-in installed by the Eclipse Marketplace. Click Help->Eclipse Marketplace in order and then input word azure in the search bar. After, you could see the Azure Toolkit for Eclipse and you could click install button to install it.
[image]

If you click the links more info->Learn more in order, you could see more infromation about the Azure Toolkit for Eclipse.
[image] 
Notice that:

You should restart your eclipse Env after getting the Azure Toolkit installed.

Hope it helps. Any concerns, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: After Successfully install azure toolkit for java in eclipse luna 4.4.2,i get the following error log file

Comment: after successfully installing azure sdk for eclipse luna(4.4.2),i am getting errors in error log file which i attached to following links.   
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/osukZ.png

Comment: another link is

Comment: Please see this official document https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-toolkit-for-eclipse-installation/. The prerequisites needs JDK V1.8 or later, but i see your error log that you use JDK 1.7. You could use JDK 1.8 and try again.

Comment: I am confirmed that the JDK version can affect the result. When I change the java version to 1.7 of my computer , I also can't see the item. So I suggest you to install JDK 1.8 to solve this problem.